# Counting new lines of the input text in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I have to write a C-program that asks for text input from the keyboard. The output of this program should be the amount of characters, the amount of words and the amount of lines that have been typed. Multiple consecutive spaces should not be counted as multiple words. 
My program counts the amount of characters and words correctly, but the output for new lines is 0. I have no idea why it does not iterate. I am a complete newbie, so I am sorry if I state a question wrong or do not provide enough information and do not see something really obvious. Thank you.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int characters = -1;
    int words = 1;
    int newlines = 0;

    cout << "Please enter your string: ";


    while ((a = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (a != ' ')
        {
            characters++;   
        }

        else if (a == ' ')
        {
            words++;    
        }

        else if (a == '\n')
        {
            newlines++;
        }


    printf("Number of Characters: %d\n", characters);
    printf("Number of Words: %d\n", words);
    printf("Number of Lines: %d\n", newlines);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: If you read them top to bottom, which condition is true *first* if the character is a newline?

Comment: You are using `getchar`. This function only takes in a character. The moment you press enter, it starts the algorithm again. 
Secondly, you are mixing `C` and `C++`. (cout vs printf)
Thirdly, why have you included `stdafx.h`

By the way, stack overflow is not the best place to solve high school problems. They are given so that you can learn how to program.

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer `stdafx.h` is the precompiled header in MSVC.

Comment: Why are you using C input in a C++ program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your attempt makes an important assumption: **words are separated by one white space**. In real world words may be separated by more than one space or even other characters (like `TAB` or `;`). Assuming the input provides words separated by one space, still you cannot ignore the **last word in a line is ended by `NL` or `EOF`**.
- Your counters must be **initialized to zero**.
- Don’t use `getchar` to get a character. **Use C++’s console input, `cin` with a `char` variable**. By default `cin` ignores white-spaces, but you need them: use `noskipws` manipulator to consider white spaces:

```
      #include "stdafx.h"
      #include <iostream>
      //...
      char a;
      while ( cin >> noskipws >> a )
      {
      // ...
```

- Use a **`switch`** instead of an `if`:

```
      while ( cin >> noskipws >> a )
      {
        switch ( a )
        {
        default:
          characters++;
          continue;

        case ' ':
          words++;
          continue; // continues with while

        case '\n':
          newlines++;
          words++;
          continue;

        case '\x1a': // ctrl + z
          break;
        }

        break;
      }

      words++;
      newlines++;
```

- The result must be printed **outside** the `while` loop. Use **C++'s console output, `cout`** instead of `printf`:

```
    cout
      << "Number of Characters: " << characters << endl
      << "Number of Words: " << words << endl
      << "Number of Lines: " << newlines;
```

- Learn how to use the **debugger**.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a != ' ')        // << this applies for `\n` AS WELL!!!
{
    characters++;   
}
else if (a == ' ')   // << obsolete! if a is not unequal to ' ', it IS ' ' 
{
    words++;    
}
else if (a == '\n') // won't ever be reached!
{
    newlines++;
}
```

Check first for the special characters:

```
if (a == ' ')
{
    words++;    
}
else if (a == '\n')
{
    newlines++;
}
else // ANYTHING else...
{
    characters++;
}
```

Your implementation, though, won't count words correctly if you have subsequent spaces! You need to remember, if last character either an alphanumeric character or any of space or newline, and only count words if previous character was alphanumeric. If you don't want to count empty lines separately either, you have to handle these analogously.

You might consider this:

```
unsigned int characters = 0; // count characters just as appear
unsigned int words = 0;      // no words on empty lines!
unsigned int newlines = 0;   // alternatively: number of lines, then start with 1
                             // (line without newline still is a line...)
bool isSpace = true; // first input character alphanumeric -> word counted...
while(a = ...)
{
    switch(a)
    {
    case '\n':
        ++newlines;
        // no break!
    case ' ':    
        isSpace = true;
        break;
    default:
        ++characters;
        if(isSpace)
        {
            ++words;
            isSpace = false;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
int count_lines(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::accumulate(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), 0, [](int prev, char c) { return c != '\n' ? prev : prev + 1; });
}
```